# update one key to all document but with different value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

let's assume my collection is :

```
[{
  "_id":1,
  "name":"john",
  "email":"john@xyz.com"
},
 {"_id":2,
  "name":"bob",
  "email":"bob@xyz.com"
},
 {"_id":3,
  "name":"tom",
  "email":"tom@xyz.com"
}]
```

and i have to update email of a every document appending with 'ma' which will ***john@xyz.com*** to **john@xyz.comma**,
 can i do it in single query?

i have tried a lot and could not find any optimal solution, any suggestion what could be the best way to achieve this.

Comment: You could look at the forEach function, but there aren't method actually  that allow update field with multiple values

Comment: @Nicolas i am not sure wether it's a nice idea to use forEach on such a huge collection. first i pull all the documents and then iterate and then i save all that. seems very inefficient and naive .

Comment: I juste give you a reflection track. It's impossible in a single query, after that do what you want

Comment: do you really want to update or you just need a concatenation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a simple for loop:

```js
var x = [{
    "_id":1,
    "name":"john",
    "email":"john@xyz.com"
},{
    "_id":2,
    "name":"bob",
    "email":"bob@xyz.com"
},{
    "_id":3,
    "name":"tom",
    "email":"tom@xyz.com"
}];

for (var o of x){
    o.email += "ma";
}

console.log(x);
```

This will iterate over each element and append "ma" to the "email" key.

Comment: collection might have upto thousands of document.

Comment: @sheelpriy so...? Thats doesn't matter at all. Here, I made an example with literally 1000 elements: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d01zk1sa/). I also added a timer.

Comment: i am not denying for your solution. thanks for that. all i was looking for that, if any better solution exist which i might be missing.